# Is there a way I can get JWT signed token to blade views in larave

Tags: php, laravel

By signing token using JWT I can access other routes which are restricted using JWT Middleware
but When I submit my blade view forms I get 419 | page has expired error

Comment: I think you should remove CSRF protection from routes that use JWT if you don't intend to use any sort of session

Comment: Thanks @apokryfos I have removed every@csrf and {{ csrf_token() }} from my views but it din't work for me

Comment: Add the paths to the exclude list in your `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Postman to reach your server page or API and add in header section Key : Authorization // Value : Bearer + MY_TOKEN (which you can get,by running keycloak.token() in your browser console once you are logged in)

Comment: Thanks @Carlo, To sign a token using postman it works and routes/api.php relies on that token, a question comes when I try to submit data  through My routes/web.php in browser